Why does my CREATE TABLE statement return an "incomplete input" error?
The cursor returns an error.
main.py:
def initialize_database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PostsData.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        title TEXT NOT NULL,
        content TEXT NOT NULL,
        link TEXT NOT NULL,
        username_id INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (username_id) REFERENCES users (id)
    )
    ''')
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        alias TEXT,
        profile_picture TEXT
    )
    ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


initialize_database()

console:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1222\Desktop\pathtoproj\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    initialize_database()
  File "C:\Users\1222\Desktop\pathtoproj\main.py", line 15, in initialize_database
    cursor.execute('''
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (posts) - incomplete input

First this worked. When connecting it to a database on my server failed I decided to go back to this option, but this time there's a problem.

Do these tables already exist in the database? If so, I bet it's a problem with the existing definition.

Since posts.username_id is a foreign key that references users.id, the users table needs to be created before the posts table for the said foreign key to be able to make that reference.
So swap the order of the table creations:
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    alias TEXT,
    profile_picture TEXT
)
''')
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    link TEXT NOT NULL,
    username_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (username_id) REFERENCES users (id)
)
''')


FWIW I thought the same thing at first but testing the OP's code it seems that sqlite doesn't mind creating a foreign key reference to a table that doesn't exist (presumably it would be a runtime error of course).
